# Timesheet Entry into Project Server Using Rest API

Tags: project-server, ms-project-server-2013

I'm trying to add timesheet entries against some specific task which is available in the MS Project Server 2013. I have ways of creating TASK in Project Server using REST endpoints, but could not find a way straight forward for the timesheet. I have gathered few details out of some scrutiny at my end:

```
To See the Complete Meta Data: 
http://>/PWA/_api/ProjectData/$metadata - You can get the field details, Where as I need to know in specific the Entity for TimeSheet.

To See the Complete Time Sheet Period Available:
http://>/PWA/_api/ProjectServer/TimeSheetPeriods - You can see all the available TimeSheet Periods.
```

I know TimeSheet stays as separate entity and doesn't belong to usual Project Entities.

My Query here to know in specific the Entity that is dealt for timesheet add & update. Please help me with endpoints including the save, publish and checkout!

Answer (score 2):

Incase anyone is still struggling with this as I was.... here's what worked for me. To replace the actual work for a given day in a task - to enter your time:

Uri:

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/ProjectServer/TimeSheetPeriods('periodid')/TimeSheet/Lines('lineid')/Work('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Method: **PATCH**

Headers:

```
 Accept - application/json;odata=verbose

 Content-type - application/json;odata=verbose

 Odata-version - 3.0

 If-Match: *
```

Body:

```
{
"__metadata": {
"type": "PS.TimeSheetWork"
},
"ActualWork": "10"
}
```

---

I entered in my times as 10 hrs.

Answer (score 1):

How are you adding the tasks? Http requests? Did you develop some app?

I tried a few ways to add actuals to timesheets already created using REST endpoints, via Postman, without success. It always responds with this error: "The security validation for this page is invalid.", I think I'm missing some headers.

This endpoints were as close as i got:

> **Submit Timesheet**
>   POST -  http://>/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/TimeSheetPeriods('periodid')/TimeSheet/submit(comment)
>
> **Update Timesheet**
>   POST - http://>/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/TimeSheetPeriods('periodid')/TimeSheet/update()

I saw this endpoints [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/project-javascript-api/jj668309(v=office.15)).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have a TimeSheet because the call returns a null object, you have to create it.
Just POST a
/TimeSheetPeriods('periodid')/createTimeSheet()

https://github.com/akordowski/Project-Server-Resources/blob/master/Project%20Server%20REST%20API%20Endpoints.md#timesheetperiods

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/project-javascript-api/jj669182(v=office.15)